# A surprisingly fun triple integral of a function over three dimensions

Tags: calculus, integration, fractions

So I decided to evaluate some double and triple integrals for fun. After a while, I came up with a sort of difficult triple integral (overall out of the integrals that I created during my session):$$\int_Df(x,y,z)dxdydz$$where$$f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{x+y+z}{xyz},D=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3,0.01\le x\le e,0.01\le y\le e,0.01\le z\le e\right\}$$This I thought that I might be able to integrate. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\begin{align}\int_Df(x,y,z)dxdydz=&\iiint_{[0.01,e]^3}\dfrac{x+y+z}{xyz}dxdydz\\\implies&\iiint_{[0.01,e]^3}\dfrac1{yz}+\dfrac1{xz}+\dfrac1{xy}dxdydz\\\implies&\iint_{[0.01,e]^2}\dfrac{e-0.01}{yz}+\ln\left(100e\right)\left(\dfrac1z+\dfrac1y\right)dydz\\\implies&\iint_{[0.01,e]^2}\dfrac1y\left(\dfrac{e-0.01+\ln(100e)}z\right)dydz\end{align}$$which can be rewritten as$$\begin{align}(e-0.01+\ln(100e))\int_{0.01}^e\dfrac{dy}y\int_{0.01}^e\dfrac{dz}z=&(e-0.01+\ln(100e))\ln^2(100e)\\=&e\ln^2(100e)-0.01\ln^2(100e)+\ln^3(100e)\\\approx&261.191476841396743068954331\end{align}$$as given by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=ePower%5Bln%5C%2840%29100e%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-0.01Power%5Bln%5C%2840%29100e%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bln%5C%2840%29100e%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D).

---

### My question

---

Did I evaluate the integral correctly, or what could I do to evaluate it over the domain that is given?

---

<sub>Note: I usually only ask if I evaluated an integral correctly if I had a lot of trouble integrating it and am unsure about my solution.</sub>

Comment: This is just an arbitrary, unmotivated integral with arbitrary, unmotivated limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $0<a<b$:

$$\begin{align}
&\iiint_{[a,b]^3}\dfrac{x+y+z}{xyz}dxdydz=\iiint_{[a,b]^3}\left(\dfrac1{yz}+\dfrac1{xz}+\dfrac1{xy}\right)dxdydz\\
\\
&=\int_a^bdx\int_a^b\frac{dy}y\int_a^b\frac{dz}z+
\int_a^b\frac{dx}x\int_a^bdy\int_a^b\frac{dz}z+
\int_a^b\frac{dx}x\int_a^b\frac{dy}y\int_a^bdz\\
\\
&=3(b-a)\ln^2\frac ba.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in this step:

\begin{align}\iint_{[0.01,e]^2}\dfrac{e-0.01}{yz}+\ln\left(100e\right)\left(\dfrac1z+\dfrac1y\right)dydz\\\implies\iint_{[0.01,e]^2}\dfrac1y\left(\dfrac{e-0.01+\ln(100e)}z\right)dydz\end{align}

The term $\ln(100 e)\frac{1}{z}$ does not have a factor $\frac{1}{y}$